# 500 Error with Express Routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've just started learning Node/Express and am currently trying to add a new page and route for it. I'm currently getting a 500 error.

My code is as follows (I've deleted the bits that aren't relevant):

app.js

```
var express = require('express');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var upload = require('./routes/upload');

var app = express();

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/upload', upload);
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

upload.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('upload', { title: 'Upload Image' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

All the routing is correct. I tried replacing the code in upload.js with the code in index.js (that comes with express-generator), and that worked.

Comment: I think you forgot to create view in `view` directory

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Can you paste the error message that is generated?

Comment: @Intervalia I'm not really sure how to check to be honest. In Javascript Console I have [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (upload, line 0). In NPM I have GET /upload 500 1.261 ms - 957

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy I have the views, I just didn't put them in my question. I've got views folder with index.html and upload.html.

Comment: The answer lies in your console output of your node application. There is probably something wrong in your EJS file. Can you post that file?

Comment: So I don't have any EJS files. If you mean upload.html, it is empty except for <% include head.html %>